# How to make an arrow place a block on impact?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve seen the ones where the blocks spawn in throughout the arrows’ trail, I just want one single block to spawn on impact of a wall or the ground or the ceiling or something. I don’t want the arrow to replace the block it hit, but put a block on the block outside of where it hit.

Comment: You'll have to add some more information. What have you tried so far? Do you want to place the block on top of the block where the arrow has landed? Or do you want to replace the block (e.g. replace a block of dirt with blue concrete)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need three different commands put in three different command blocks, here they are:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Arrow,tag=!kill] add kill {inGround:1b}

/execute @e[type=Arrow,tag=kill] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ dirt
/kill @e[type=Arrow,tag=kill]
```

The first and second should be put into a repeat command block and the third one should be in a chain block. It should look like this:

[image: 1]]

If you want to change the block, change where it says "dirt" to any other valid block. If by any chance you need more explanation over this, ask it and I'll take more screenshots.

Comment: Oops! The provided commands only work in Java Edition. The OP wants a solution for Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Good point. I guess I didn't notice at the time... are you in need of a answer, @ExpertCoder14 ? Also, I guess since the OP neve got around to try it, I didn't get any feedback.